# t-sql include column if condition exists

Tags: sql, t-sql

If I have an sql statement:

```
select call_id, title, description, due_date
from calls
```

I want to include a column if the condition `due_date < getdate()` is true.

I was thinking this column would be of type `bit`, and be set to 1 if condition is true and 0 if condition is false.

Know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT call_id, title, description, due_date, 
CASE WHEN due_date < getdate() THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE 0 END overdue
FROM calls
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
  call_id,
  title,
  description,
  due_date,
  case when due_date < getdate() then 1 else 0 end
from calls
```